# Redirect additional domains to the single in use-domain using Apache mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^someparkeddomain.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hxtp://www.thedomainUsed.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.someparkeddomain.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hxtp://www.thedomainUsed.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anotherparkeddomain.co.uk 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hxtp://www.thedomainUsed.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.anotherparkeddomain.co.uk 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hxtp://www.thedomainUsed.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

is what I have but doesnt seem to do anything :/ (hxtp because I am new user not spammer!)

redirect is working though as I use it for something else.

Answer (score 1):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

have a look at that

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are correct, though it would be simpler to do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)someparkeddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)anotherparkeddomain.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.thedomainused.co.uk/$1 [R=301]
```

You don't need `L` flag because redirects are always final.

If this is not working, it's because you're putting it in the wrong place. Put them in the default (i.e. first) virtual host or (if there is no default virtual host) in the main section and make sure you don't have virtual hosts set up for `someparkeddomain.com` and `anotherparkeddomain.co.uk`.